# Android: Building release instead of running the app

Tags: android, gradle, assemble

**Issue:**

I am currently coding an external lib for an Android App I am building. Within the lib (the file to be exported as .aar), I wrote a Test Application, in order for me not to have to export the lib 1000's of times to test it. I worked 100% until last night when suddenly it started building releases when I click on the run icon.

**What I did before it started doing the was the following:**

I clicked on the Gradle option on the right side of the IDE, clicked the green +, and added the files from the gradle files. I am not sure if this caused the issue but this was when it started acting this way.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I want the `test app` to run as an application. This is how it used to happen but it no longer does. I am thinking the problem lies in the `.gradle`

**Screenshot:**

[image: The application structure]

Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Thank you in advance,

Owen

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Since the last task I performed was a `build.assembleRelease` the app changed the run configuration to AssembleRelease. I simply has to change the run configuration to run app.